# TSQL equality between year() and conversion from string to int

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select top 100 pId from Product
    inner join Code on cFKId = pId
    where year(pToDate) = convert(int, substring(@term,1,4)) 
        and month(pToDate) = convert(int, substring(@term,5,2))
        and codeValue = @value
```

The variable `@term` is a `varchar` and has the form `YYYYMM`, no exception and `pToDate` is a `datetime`.
   What this query is supposed to do is: take the first 100 ids from the table `Product` which have the same year as the first four digits from `term` and the month being the same as the last two digits from `@term`.

I also tried with `cast(substring(@term,1,4) to int)`.

The variable `value` should be of no interest here.

The values are correct, both the months and the years and the values of the variable `@term`. 
The problem is that it returns an empty query although there are hundreds of values in the Database.

If i print the values for the conversions it gives me a table like 
`2008 | 8`
`2008 | 9`
`2008 | 10`
...and so on.

These are the exact values i get if i write the years and months only.

Where did i go wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: Are you sure that's where your problem is?  Try removing the join to code, and the codeValue from the where clause and see if you still get no results

Comment: Try: `where pToDate >= CAST( @term+'01' AS DATE) AND pToDate <  DATEADD(month, 1, CAST( @term+'01' AS DATE)) and codeValue = @value`

Comment: @ypercube you basically put my answer on your comment.

Comment: @FionaT, i tried it and still no results.

Comment: @Lamak: I don't see (the answer.) Please write it so we can upvote.

Comment: @ypercube, i'll try it right now and return with feedback

Comment: @ypercube Oh, no, the answer I was about to post :-)

Comment: @ypercube, it works, thanks a lot. now, could you tell me what was the problem initially? so i won't repeat it in the future, if you know?

Comment: The original code with YEAR/MONTH and CONVERT works for me.

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with the original code (except that it's not sargable, it wouldn't use indexes on `pToDate`). You probably tested it with some `@value` that did not appear at `codeValue`.